# Angularjs ng-include disables bootstrap modal()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html page with a div:

```
<div id="divLogin" ng-include="'App_2/View/login.html'"></div>
```

And my login.html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myLoginModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h5 id="lblLoginError" class="alert-info">{{errorMessage}}</h5>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="User" class="sr-only">User</label>
                    <input type="text" name="User" id="LoginUser" ng-model="userName" class="form-control" placeholder="User">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="key" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="key" id="LoginPassword" ng-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" data-loading-text="Loading..." id="btnLogin" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="hideModal()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller I call the method showModal from my loginModal service:

```
app.factory('loginModal', function () {

    var loginBtn = angular.element("#btnLogin");
    var loginModal = angular.element('#myLoginModal');

    return {
        resetBtn: function () {
            loginBtn.button('reset');
        },

        loadBtn: function () {
            loginBtn.button('loading');
        },

        showModal: function () {
            loginModal.modal('show');
        },

        hideModal: function () {
            loginModal.modal('hide');
            loginBtn.button('reset');
        }
    };
});
```

If I add the html from login.html directly in divLogin everything works fine 
but when I use ng-include the model dosen't open when I call modal(). 
The `angular.element('#myLoginModal')` gets the element in both cases so the modal is loaded correctly from what I can see.

Do I have to rebind bootstrap modal() function or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables seems to be instantiated before the render of the modal was completed by ng-include. Even if I could se that the modal object were rendered in my service variables they were in some way garbage. 
After resetting them in the service methods everything worked fine when loading the login view in ng-include.

Working solution:

```
showModal: function () {
    loginModal = angular.element('#myLoginModal');
    loginModal.modal('show');
},
```